# derivability of a function defined by an infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis

Let's define $f$ as $f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^4 + n^2 x^2}$ and I want to prove that this function isn't differentiable at the origin. To do so, I tried to use the definition, which seems the way to go. I have thought about maybe trying to bound the left and right limits in the definition of derivative but I get nowhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Notice $$\frac{1}{n^{4}+n^{2}x^{2}}=\frac{1}{x^{2}}[\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2+x^2}]$$
So summing gives $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2+x^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+x^2}$$
Luckily we have a closed form for the second sum, and $$f(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{6x^2}-\frac{\pi x\coth{\pi x}-1}{2x^4}$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Nice solution, but I still think there must be a way to do this by somehow showing the limit of the definition of derivative doesn't exist.

Comment: Well you could do that by computing the derivative of $f$ and letting $x$ go to $0$, but it seems if you do that you will find $f$ is actually differentiable at $0$

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\frac{1}{n^{4}+n^{2}x^{2}}\le\frac{1}{n^4}\quad\forall x\in\Bbb R,
$$
the series is uniformly convergent on $\Bbb R$. Now
$$
\Bigl(\frac{1}{n^{4}+n^{2}x^{2}}\Bigr)'=-\frac{2\,n^2\,x}{(n^{4}+n^{2}x^{2})^2}
$$
and
$$
\Bigl|\Bigl(\frac{1}{n^{4}+n^{2}x^{2}}\Bigr)'\Bigr|\le\frac{2\,x}{n^6}\quad\forall x\in\Bbb R.
$$
Th series of the derivatives is uniformly convergent on any bounded interval. Then $f$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R$ and
$$
f'(x)=-2\,x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{(n^{4}+n^{2}x^{2})^2}.
$$